# Functoriality of sheaf Cohomology

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, sheaf-cohomology

Let $f:Y\rightarrow X$ be a morphism of schemes. I would like to construct a natural map of homologies $$H^{q}(X,F)\rightarrow H^{q}(Y,f^{*}(F))$$ where $F$ is a sheaf on X. My idea is to take an injective resolution $I^{\bullet}$ of $F$ and $J^{\bullet}$ an injective resolution of $f^{*}(F)$. Of course the resolution $I^{\bullet}$ is flasque, so I think if I prove that $f^{*}(I^{\bullet})$ is flasque then I am done because there is a map $I^{\bullet}\rightarrow f_{*}f^{*} I^{\bullet}$. But I am stuck on how to do this. Any ideas?

Comment: $f^*(J^*)$ doesn't make sense because $J$ lives on $Y$ already. (Also, please try to use different notation for pullback and complexes - one common solution is to use `J^{\bullet}` which produces $J^\bullet$, something that's visually distinct from pullback.)

Comment: Sorry you are right I edited, so do you know @KReiser why $f^{*}(I^{\bullet})$ is flasque? ( if it is not I would like a counterexample

Comment: Hold your horses, you only just edited your question! It's not completely absurd to find an example where $f^*(I^\bullet)$ is not flasque - let $X$ be the spectrum of a field and take an injective resolution consisting of vector spaces. Since the objects of the resolution are free, their pullbacks are as well, and it's very uncommon for something to be both free and injective. By the way, I found [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2461651/pullback-of-sheaf-cohomology) which looks like it might resolve your issues - what do you think?

Comment: But even in your example we could have that is flasque.

Comment: Not in general. Try $Y=\Bbb A^1$ for example.